# What is the memory location of referenced variables?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
  int i = 10;
  int &j = i;
  int k = 20;
  j=k;
  cout << i << j << k;
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is 202020.

In above snippet what will be the memory location of i and j.
Do they have same memory location or different?

Comment: Do you understand what `&` means?

Comment: "Could anybody please justify the output of the following program?" - sure, I do: "Calm down, the output of this program is completely justified."

Comment: Yes. It means address of "j"

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/17153/

Comment: @ricky no it doesn't. `&` has a different meaning in a type than it does as an operator.

Comment: @ricky no, it doesn't (at least not in this context). You better read a beginner C++ book or tutorial before making wrong assumptions.

Comment: I got it. Now I have one confusion. Is the memory location of i and j would be the same?

Answer (score 3):

`j` is reference to `i`, so whenever you change value of `j` i's value will also going to change.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do some more learning so that you can figure these things out in future but lets walk through your program:

```
  int i = 10;  //Makes an int with value 10
  int &j = i;  //Makes a reference which points to i
  int k = 20;  //Makes an int with value 20
  j=k;         //You are making the reference the area that 
               //j represents (ie. i) the same as k
  cout << i << j << k;  //j = 20 therefore i = 20
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 10;
```

i had been allocated on the stack, the address of which points to the value 10.

```
int &j = i;
```

j has been allocated on the stack, the address of which has been assigned to the address of i, the address of which points to the value 10.  The address of i and j are the same at this point.

```
int k = 20;
```

k has been allocated on the stack, the address of which points to the value 20.

```
j=k;
```

The the value at address j has been assigned to the value at address k (20).

At this point, i and j have the same address, the value at which is 20.

k has a different address, but the value at k's address is also 20.

Comment: The talk of addresses in confusing. Addresses may come into it in the implementation, but in reality a reference is an alias for an object.